# How to get certificate serial number from p12 in Java

Tags: java, xml, sign

I need to sign xml in Java with a certificate. When I like to get certificate serial number I get null. I wan't to use keystore because I must make java stored procedure on oracle database to sign xml with specified certificate stored on database file system.

short example

```
KeyStore p12 = KeyStore.getInstance("pkcs12");
p12.load(new FileInputStream("c:/cert/mycert.p12"), "PASSWORD".toCharArray());
Enumeration e = p12.aliases();
String alias = (String) e.nextElement();
System.out.println("Alias certifikata:" + alias);
Key privateKey = p12.getKey(alias, "PASSWORD".toCharArray());

KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry keyEntry
        = (KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry) p12.getEntry(alias, new KeyStore.PasswordProtection("Geslo123#".toCharArray()));

X509Certificate cert = (X509Certificate) keyEntry.getCertificate();

System.out.println("cert name:" + cert.getSubjectX500Principal().getName());
System.out.println("cert serial number: " + cert.getSerialNumber());
```

I must provide serial number and issuer name in signature (signed xml)..

```
KeyInfoFactory keyInfoFactory = sigFactory.getKeyInfoFactory();
X509IssuerSerial x509IssuerSerial = keyInfoFactory.newX509IssuerSerial(cert.getSubjectX500Principal().getName(), cert.getSerialNumber());
```

Comment: So to be clear, `System.out.println("cert serial number: " + cert.getSerialNumber());` prints `null`?

Comment: Can you try running: `keytool -list -storetype pkcs12 -keystore my_debug_keystore.p12 -storepass debug` or 
`keytool -v -list -storetype pkcs12 -keystore my_debug_keystore.p12 -storepass debug`?

You should get a result like this, which contains the serial number: 

Alias name: 2
Creation date: Aug 17, 2014
Entry type: PrivateKeyEntry
Certificate chain length: 1
Certificate[1]:
Owner: CN=sixminute, OU=, O=, C=IE
Issuer: CN=sixminute, OU=, O=, C=IE
**Serial number: 2d36623161363935353a31336165303361636133313a2d38303030**
Valid from: ...